# Breadcrum issue after embeding advance search on home page:magento2

Tags: magento2, php, layout, advanced-search, template-override

I have moved the advance search form on home page with the custom template as:

```
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout  /etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" name="catalogsearch_advanced_form"
           template="Your_Theme::advance-search.phtml"/>
     </referenceContainer>
  </page>
```

Now issue is whenever i visit an page from home page the breadcrumb always includes the advance search in it like this:
[image]

How this can be fixed? so it can show what page user on in the breadcrumb?

Comment: Which XML file did you edit?

Comment: default.xml from parent theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this By Overriding the Block `Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form` and return the parent  like this:

```
public function _prepareLayout() {
    return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::_prepareLayout();
}
```

So actually in the module they have returned the custom Breadcrumb structure that we dont required in this case.

Hopefully it will help for someone else out there too.